# httpd.conf @ Windows

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, webmatrix

I've created PHP project with MS WebMatrix and copied the CakePHP into it. It promped:

> URL rewriting is not properly configured on your server.

But, except that, everything is fine:

> Your version of PHP is 5.2.8 or higher.
>
> Your tmp directory is writable.
>
> The FileEngine is being used for core caching. To change the config edit APP/Config/core.php
>
> Your database configuration file is present.
>
> Cake is able to connect to the database.

I believe I should just edit httpd.conf file (CakePHP documentation told me so) but I couldn't find such a file at all... is it hidden somewhere or is there any GUI configurator? I'm new to Windows so really, don't know where to search and Google told me nothing but obvious Linux directory...

I could just upload all the files to the server and work from there but that's just not really handy.

Comment: That file is apache server config, so in your case you must change web.config instead for rewriting. Found this, may helps you. http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1636/URL-Rewrites-on-IIS7-Windows-hosts

Comment: It should be in the `conf` folder located in the directory where Apache was installed to.  Did you install Apache manually or use an installer or something like XAMPP?

Comment: @drew010 I used Windows Web Platform Installer so I don't even know what happened ;-) there is no "Apache" called folder I could find except that at NetBeans directory but that probably don't count...

Comment: @renamr web.config of my .NET installation?

Comment: No, in the CakePHP folder, follow and read the link i posted. Webmatrix installs an IIS server not an Apache.

Comment: @renamr did you add this link with edit? I didn't see it! It answered my question! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: I edited it later. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit .htaccess file in the app root folder. IIS configuration needs some modification in the htaccess files in your cakephp project.

Hope it will work for you. Please ask if it not worked for you.